# How to solve Talib library is not import error when deploying website with Render

Tags: python, flask, render, ta-lib

I made a study using the Talib library with Python flask. I'm trying to make the web application we created with Github run, but I'm having trouble installing the talib library.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj1lX.png)

Trying to run the web application we created with Github

Comment: Do not post text as image and include the error directly into your question.